# Using specific font for the equation in XeLaTex

Tags: xetex, equations, fontspec, mathspec

I want to use a specific font for a specific formula in XeLaTeX. Usually, the math font can be set up using `mathspec` package.

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Humor Sans}
```

I can also use a specific font for a part of the text using `\newfontfamily` command:

```
\newfontfamily\humor{Humor Sans}
{\humor text }
```

How can I use a specific font for a single equation:

```
%Want Humor Sans only here!!
 \begin{equation}
   C = A + B
\end{equation}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was only for a single equation, I would be tempted to compile the equation in the `standalone` class, and then include it as a PDF graphic in the other [primary] document.  Here's how.  First, compile the file `ComicEq.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Comic Sans MS}
\begin{document}
$C = A + B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then, the primary document includes it as a graphic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  \includegraphics{ComicEq}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]